# Lenovo P50 crashes gnome-shell regularly after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.1 using Wayland (default)

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, gnome-shell, thinkpad, wayland

I've been using Ubuntu on my slightly aging but never failing Lenovo Thinkpad P50 (20ENCTO1WW) laptop since I got it in 2017. It has survived with just a few bumps all the upgrades. Since the stable 20.04.x LTS version I decided to upgrade only to LTS versions. I'm now experiencing regular crashes of the gnome-shell. This results in going back to the login screen and having all running desktop applications crashing along with it. This has been reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1977666. But in my case it crashes on more occasions. After trying all kinds of things with other kernels and proposed updates, desperate to keep my productivity, I decided first to backup and reinstall the 20.04 back. But much to my surprise my gnome-shell was still crashing, so I went back to 22.04.1

I also discovered that I can't reproduce the crashes when logging in with Ubuntu on Xorg. So quite sure it only happens using Wayland.

Did anybody have a proper fix for this?

Comment: I have been looking at version numbers of kernels under 20.04 and 22.04 whilst trying to solve my unrelated problem. I know that when I first installed 20.04 it used kernel 5.4 and by 20.04.5 it was at 5.15, the same as 22.04. It might be worth checking that you are comparing like with like, as far a kernel versions are concerned.

Comment: Yeah I upgraded up to 5.19.x but to no avail to fix this problem as well. Now I'm back at the current default 5.15.0-47-generic to keep things simple to reproduce

Comment: I see, but did you ever have 5.4, under which it may have worked ?

Comment: Well yeah I probably did have that that kernel at some point, and I didn't have these problems with my laptop until the new bios and 22.04 came along. I have just recently reverted back to the bios version 1.68 and also to the previous firmware version of the onboard controller. If that doesn't improve stability I might think of trying older kernel versions

Answer (score 0):

So far, the bug does not seem to appear when disabling wayland:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment #WaylandEnable=false and make sure it now reads `WaylandEnable=false`

Save the file and reboot.

Ofcourse this is not a fix, but just a workaround!